# Position elements at corners of draggable image

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I currently have. I want the 4 circles to position themselves on the four corners of an image when that image is clicked. Wherever the image is positioned.

```js
$("img").click(function() {

  

});
$( function() {
    $( "img" ).draggable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<img id="resizable" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
<img id="resizable" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
<img id="resizable" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
<img id="resizable" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
<br>
<i id="top-left" class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
<i id="top-right" class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
<i id="bottom-left" class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
<i id="bottom-right" class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
```

Comment: Wrap the images in divs. Make the icons relative. Use top, left, bottom, and right in css to position them.

Comment: I can't do that because the images will not be set into the page when it is loaded. In the website I am creating, the images will be added on by the user.

Comment: That is no excuse.

Comment: Really makes no difference when they get added, wrapping in a container is the practical way to do it. Very easy to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are potentially many ways of doing this, As John mentioned above you can wrap them in individual divs and make the icons relative (This can be added into your js upon image creation by the user and is fairly simple).

The other alternative is that you can use the same div wrapping approach as above but instead use the flex-box display, the image in question will have a div wrapping it that will have the display set to "flex" and then the properties of "justify" and "align" to set the position of each icon dependent on where you wan them placed. This is also implemented upon creation by the user through your js and leads to scale-able reactive design.

You could also use the grid layout in a similar way but flex-box in my opinion is easier to use and understand.

Here is a great resource for getting to know it.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Could you write the code and explain how it is done, because I tried but it didn't work. Thank You!